# i have 2 discount codes, only one can apply?

Tags: magento

i have 2 discount codes in my magento store, one gives the customers 10% off discount and the other gives the customers 20% discounts. how can i keep them both available for the customer but only one can be used.
how to keep both discount codes available but without the ability to combine them ?

refer to www.simplysterling.com.au , the coupon codes are 10OFF and 20OFF , only the 20OFF is working the 10OFF is not even if i used the same setting for both rules
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever a customer will apply the second coupon code,after she/he has entered first coupon code the first one will be reverted back and second one will be applicable.

Comment: refer to www.simplysterling.com.au , the coupon codes are 10OFF and 20OFF , only the 20OFF is working the 10OFF is not even if i used the same setting for both rules

Comment: I do not see any option to add coupon code on the site.

Comment: thanks for your reply,if you add a product to your cart and click on cart and you can apply the coupon there . thanks again

Comment: ok, got the place to enter the code,try to create the coupon again you might have missed something.

Comment: Thanks @Muk, i don't know why this code is not working i just created a new code with the same settings, but with different coupon code and it's working fine. Thanks again for your help